# Is a class only a template, or is it also an instance of itself?

Tags: python-3.x, class

A class is a perfect object to encapsulate my data and methods that act on it.  I only need one class instance.  Because the class has global scope below its level, I'd like to use the class name for all data management.

An alternative would be to create a class instance and then pass it around.  Another alternative would be to make the instance global, but then people might yell at me. :)

Does a class object behave exactly as if it were an instance?  Does it keep all of the 'self.' variables after they're modified?  Do I need to add the statement '@staticmethod' before every method to do this?

Comment: In a case like this, my recommendation is to make your class a module instead. All variables can then be stored as global variables, and methods can simply be top-level functions. Don't use a class unless you intend on instantiating it multiple different times. Otherwise, you don't really see the benefits of a class and questions  like static/instance just cause more confusion than they're worth.

Comment: As to people yelling at you for using globals, I would argue they have the wrong mindset about the problem. Python doesn't provide any real protections on class access anyway, so using globals is really no different.

Comment: A class object *is* an instance, but it's an instance of its metaclass (which is `type` unless explicitly stated otherwise). I'm not sure what you mean by "has global scope below its level".

Comment: @chepner, What I meant is that all functions defined at the same level as the class can use the class name.  If the class was defined inside a function, then it can't be accessed outside the function unless it's made global.  I don't know if that's the right way to describe scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python has a Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop. Let's use it to see the difference between static and member variables.

```
$ ipython                                                                                09:48:10
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:41:53)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     DINGAS = 'Dingas'
   ...:     def __init__(self, x):
   ...:         self.x = x
   ...:     
   ...:     @staticmethod
   ...:     def do_work(x):
   ...:         return x + 1
   ...:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def say_hello(cls):
   ...:         print('Hello')

In [3]: foo = Foo(1)

In [4]: foo.x
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: foo.DINGAS
Out[5]: 'Dingas'

In [6]: Foo.x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d41f169aaa8f> in <module>()
----> 1 Foo.x

AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'x'

In [7]: Foo.DINGAS
Out[7]: 'Dingas'

In [8]: Foo.say_hello()
Hello
```

As you see, a class acts like an instance if the variable is at the same level as functions or the function has one of the `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` decorators.

EDIT: It's worth noting that the choice of the variable name `self` for the first parameter of instance methods is an arbitrary but consistent choice across Python.